# how to clear % from echo -n in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to clear `%` sign from the end of the line in my shell script, I'm getting input from the command line when I hit the enter unexpectedly I'm getting the `%` as shown below:

```
The official language of Romania is Romanian%
```

***My Script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the name of a country: "
read COUNTRY

echo -n "The official language of $COUNTRY is "

case $COUNTRY in

  Lithuania)
    echo -n "Lithuanian"
    ;;

  Romania | Moldova)
    echo -n "Romanian"
    ;;

  Italy | "San Marino" | Switzerland | "Vatican City")
    echo -n "Italian"
    ;;

  *)
    echo -n "unknown"
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I don't have any clue how to remove this sign from the end of the line, could you please help me out in this issue!

Comment: Presumably the `%` is your shell prompt - you are seeing it appended to the string *because* you are using echo's `-n` flag (which says *don't* print a newline)

Comment: @steeldriver Exactly, but in a real project, it's gonna be not good. I want to remove from the end of the line, is the anything I can do for this?

Comment: Add an `echo` after `esac` and before `exit 0`. (Because `echo -n` does not append a newline character, and as a result the cursor remains after the last output character.)

Comment: @AlexP Thanks You nailed it! Thank you very much you solved my problem, I think you write answer for this because to help someone else!

Comment: ... or simply omit the `-n` since that doesn't seem to be the behavior that you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add an `echo` after `esac` and before `exit 0`.

  That's because `echo -n` does not append a newline character, and as a result the cursor remains after the last output character.

Otherwise,

- Change all the `echo -n` within the `case`...`esac` with plain `echo`.

  Normally, one uses `echo -n` only when they *explicitly* want to suppress adding a newline at the end of output.